# DNN MVC Form jumps to top after submit, with or without ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

I used either form or Ajax.beginform to create a DNN module, In both cases after installing module, The submit click causes jump to top of the page.

I tried using jquery preventdefault and return false in submit button click but had no good effect.

How to correct this in DNN and MVC?

**Code:**

```
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Framework.DnnWebViewPage<MyModule2.Models.TestFormModel>
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestFormv";
    Layout = "../shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<form action="testform" method="post" id="frmTest">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group d-flex flex-md-row align-items-center">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-label mr-2" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control mr-2" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "" })
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use CSS to force a min-height for the container/div, stopping the content shifting after the elements load. Without a code snippet, it is only a guess/workaround

Comment: hi, using code above clicking submit button refreshes the page to get a correct result, but when page comes backs scroll position is not maintained. and page is at top.